# Display options for email

Tags: c#, outlook, email, preferences

I am displaing one particular mail message. I wonder if i can change display preferences. I want to change options to display pictures embedded in mail body. I access to mail in that way:

```
Outlook.Application outLookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Inspector inspector = outLookApp.ActiveInspector();
Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = outLookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Outlook.MailItem item = inbox.Items[1];
item.Display();
```

Comment: can you clarify you question a bit, are you wanting to show a embed imange or are you wanting open the email so that it show images that have been blocked for download ?

Comment: I want to show email with embedded images and without them. I want to on/off this setting

Answer (score 1):

There might be a workaround to create something you are talking about with this email display.  Like create your own displayer of the MailItem.  But there is no way that I can find to turn it on and off.  You can dig [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx) to find out deeper features of the Outlook libraries.  You might try to find the settings here and see if they give a way to change them.